# Не работает reinit у slick слайдер

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, не подскажете как правильно настроить реинит у слик слайдера?смотрел в инете, но там в основном используют сложную логику на jquery.

Пытался сделать что то подобное, но не работает

```
$('.slick-carousel').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 4, 
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true, 
    dots: false ,
    infinite:true,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1280,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 3,
              infinite: true,
              dots: true
            }
          },
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings:"unslick",
        },
      ]
  });

  function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-2);
  }


  $('.slick-carousel').slick('reinit')
```

Comment: А разве есть такой метод `reinit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно привязаться к ширине экрана, то проверьте её с помощью `$(window).width()`. Например, так:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $('.slick-carousel').slick('unslick');
  // затем просто снова инициализируйте слайдер
  $('.slick-carousel').slick();
}
```

Правда я совершенно не понимаю зачем вам это :)

Comment: спасибо,получилось